# Identifying privacy violation in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, privacy

I am facing random crashes in my application running on iOS 10.2. Attached my crash log below. I have checked few forums and some answers suggests to include missing permissions in info.plist. But I have already added the necessary privacy access keys and still I'm facing the issue. Im not sure which is the cause for the privacy violence issue. Is there a way to identify which key i have missed to add in info.plist from the log or in any other way?

```
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182b59d74 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182b5649c abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182b564c8 system_set_sfi_window + 10
3  TCC                            0x185dca328 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80 + 258
4  TCC                            0x185dca224 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 702
5  TCC                            0x185dcd330 __tccd_send_block_invoke + 348
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x182c5efcc _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 80
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x182c5ef3c _xpc_connection_call_reply + 40
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x182a161bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x182a24a4c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 732
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182a2634c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182a260ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182c1f2a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182c1ed8c start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571603/app-crashes-with-crashing-due-to-privacy-violation-when-trying-to-access-con

Comment: I am not using contacts. My app access location, photo library,camera and headphone jack. I have added key/values needed for these permission(added external protocol key with hardware bundle identifiers). But still I'm facing this issue. Thats why I'm confused of what I'm missing.

Comment: Check for typos in your Info.plist keys, but otherwise... are these crashing on your device or on somebody else's device?  Is it possible the OS installation is corrupted, or that the device was jailbroken with a buggy jailbreak?

Comment: these crashes occurs on users devices. I guess OS is not corrupted nor jaibroken since its happening for multiple users.

Comment: Are using any third party libraries? check them they are updated to latest version, may they have been causing crashing.

Comment: @Arasuvel just wondering how that could cause this issue. Please give me some hint on what could be the problem.

Comment: @prabhu were you able to solve this?

Comment: @prabhu Is your app displaying any web content? Users can long-press on images in web views and select to save them to the camera roll. Starting with iOS 10 this causes an app to crash that didn't ask for permission to access the camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my case is I added every single Privacy permission possible and labelled them with what they requested, like "Bluetooth" for the permission to access Bluetooth accessories.  Then I ran the app and watched for which permission request came in.  It took me a few minutes to add them all in but it solved my issue.  In the end, I had requested Photo Library Access but had forgotten to request Photo Library Addition, that permission was only required when a user attempted to share an image and then hit the option "Save" instead of actually sharing it via SMS/Email/*

Answer (score 0):

TCCAccessRequest Belongs to the keyboard extension. If you access other things from within, it requires full access else it get terminated.
If its not full access the cause could mean another access right. Full access include a lot privileges like location.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `TCC __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80` is related to `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`. See [How do I prevent a WKWebView from presenting the Camera modal if a user has denied access to the camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514435/how-do-i-prevent-a-wkwebview-from-presenting-the-camera-modal-if-a-user-has-deni) for why this may be happening.

My best educated guess is that the `2.80` is some internal constant related to the particular privacy permissions. In this case, microphone permissions.