# Unable to access Microphone and Camera in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

`WKWebView` is not asking permission for camera and microphone in the app. When I load the same url in safari browser it asks the permission for camera and microphone, and video call works perfectly. But when I embed this in `WKWebView` permission is not asked even I have given both camera and microphone permission in plist file. The same thing is not working even in `UIWebView` and safari view controller. I have referred below links but still its not working.
[Enable Camera and Mic access in wkwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview) ,
[How do I prevent a WKWebView from presenting the Camera modal if a user has denied access to the camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514435/how-do-i-prevent-a-wkwebview-from-presenting-the-camera-modal-if-a-user-has-deni)
Can anybody provide any solution?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: please reply if you have found any solution.I am also stuck in same situation.

Comment: This answer may be a solution. [Enable camera and mic access in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the asking permission for camera and microphone in the app **yourself**?

You have the full control over your app.

```
    //Camera
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
        if response {
            //access granted
        } else {

        }
    }

    //Photos
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if photos == .notDetermined {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
            if status == .authorized{
                ...
            } else {}
        })
    }
```

If all granted, then do the `js`  video call.

If not, show tips for the use to grant it.

- And, it's easy to do that `js` call `native`, `native` call `js`