# __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__

Tags: ios, permissions, crash, privacy, ios-permissions

In Crashlytics, I can see iOS 10 users are getting this crash frequently. However, when I test in Simulator using iPhone 7/10.2, I'm unable to reproduce the crash. In my plist, I already have strings for

> NSCalendarsUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription, and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription.

Here is the stacktrace from Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183765d74 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18376249c <redacted> + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1837624c8 abort_with_payload + 10
3  TCC                            0x1869d6328 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80 + 258
4  TCC                            0x1869d6224 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 702
5  TCC                            0x1869d9330 __tccd_send_block_invoke + 348
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x18386afcc _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 80
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x18386af3c _xpc_connection_call_reply + 40
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1836221bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x183630a4c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 732
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18363234c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836320ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18382b2a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18382ad8c start_wqthread + 4
```

Any clue how to reproduce or fix this? I do allow user to access contacts, but I am not prompted for any permission when I test that feature in simulator. However, when the user accesses the camera from my app, the simulator does prompt me for a permission. That makes me think that a string is not needed for accessing contacts.

Comment: For me it was the new: **Privacy - Tracking Usage Description**, that was missing in the info.plist, after implementing the `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to add a string for `NSCameraUsageDescription` in the plist because user is allowed to take photos.

Answer (score 31):

If you're seeing these crashes on iPhone X and you use Touch ID/Face ID, the reason might be a lack of `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` key in your Info.plist. The key was added in iOS 11 and looks like it might have become mandatory after iOS 11.3, given that I see a spike of crashes on iPhone X after iOS 11.3 was released. It's vaguely documented by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html):

> NSFaceIDUsageDescription (String - iOS). This key lets you describe the reason your app uses Face ID.
>
> Important: To protect user privacy, an iOS app that links on or after iOS 11 and that would access Face ID if the hardware supports it, must statically declare the intent to do so. Include the NSFaceIDUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. If your app attempts to access Face ID without a corresponding purpose string, your app may exit.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 11 and later.

Interestingly enough, I wasn't able to reproduce the crash on iOS 11.3 on my development iPhone X, maybe it behaves differently in debug or TestFlight builds. Still worth adding the key when you use Face ID in your app, if we believe Apple's documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Max. Very very helpful.

Comment: let context = LAContext()
        var error:NSError?
        var status = false
        
        status = context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error)
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if context.biometryType == .faceID {
            }
        }  I am just checking whether biometryType is faceID or not, why on earth would this crash my app?

Comment: @Max, you saved me

Comment: @Max do we need to add this key even if we are using only for Touch ID ?

Comment: My understanding is that even if you use Touch ID, when this app is running on devices with Face ID, it will switch to that. I'm not quite sure if there's a way to prevent that switch automatically, so it's probably advisable to add the key in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Let's understand two things.

In the plist file there so many privacy keys for example camera usage, contact usage location usage, face id usage, etc... if you miss any of the keys and try to use those features you will get a crash, so use keys and description for avoding crash.

2nd thing is, especially for **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**, if you were using this key from **above iOS 6** and **below iOS 11.3** then you will not get any crash, but after **iOS 11.3 and later** you need to add one more key which is **NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription**.

At the same time, you may use both keys if your app is iOS 8 or 9 or above to latest iOS 11.3 and higher.

[Reference for all the keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

Answer (score 6):

The `__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__` crash happens whenever there is a **mandatory** permission string missing on the app's plist. Permissions level are changed by Apple with new iOS versions sometimes. So code that was working will start breaking with iOS updates that have new requirements for the plists.

You should evaluate what of the permissions listed on all the answers here may affect you (`NSFaceIDUsageDescription`, `NSCameraUsageDescription`, `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`, others?) as you may not be using any of those features on your app.

In my case, we support a Bluetooth BLE device and from iOS13 there was a new mandatory permission needed: **`NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`** so I added to my plist:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We use Bluetooth to connect to your ... while the app is in the background</string>
```

And that fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

**Case 1**

I got the same crash report when attempting to read files using a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` without first calling `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on the returned `URL`.

**Case 2**

Here's another possible (corner) case:

If you use `EKEventEditViewController` to add events to the user's calendar, the `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` key in your info.plist **might not be enough**!

If the user attempts to add invitees to the event, the `NSContactsUsageDescription` key is also required. Otherwise, when the user attempts to search through their contacts, the privacy violation occurs and the app crashes.

Comment: Thank you! Case 2 drove me crazy for months!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a iphone X running iOS 14. Solved the problem adding NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription to my info.plist file.

acording to this forum : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/100732

Answer (score 1):

You must need to **grant the permission** from user to access the AddressBook.

```
  #import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

  // Request authorization to Address Book
  ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

  if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
      if (granted) {
          // First time access has been granted, add the contact
          [self _addContactToAddressBook];
      } else {
          // User denied access
          // Display an alert telling user the contact could not be added
      }
    });
  }
  else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // The user has previously given access, add the contact
    [self _addContactToAddressBook];
  }
  else {
    // The user has previously denied access
    // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
  }
```

There is update on iOS 9.0 and above:

From Apple website :

Important
The Address Book UI framework is deprecated in iOS 9. Use the APIs defined in the [ContactsUI](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui) framework instead. To learn more, see ContactsUI.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in my app and **EVEN THOUGH I didn't need to use the camera,** I needed to add the tags:

NSCameraUsageDescription;
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription;
NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription

This is because within the app **we have a webview** to open a website, and within that website there is an option in which the user can send files, in case he is using an iPhone, the option "Take a shot" appears, which uses the camera, and it was this is what was causing the app to break with a lack of authorization

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I forgot to add `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` to the Info.plist. There was also an error message in the Xcode debug console about it.