# iOS app crashes caught by crashlytics

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics

I fixed so many crashes in my app using (Fabrics) crashlytics. The ones showing my project's code were easy to fix.

But there are some crashes which are refering to OS code (probably). And I have no idea how to fix them.

I made the issue public and you can see it [here](http://crashes.to/s/634f0db7ca5).

This is the crash log:

```
com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3e593c search_method_list(method_list_t const*, objc_selector*) + 84
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3e0e58 getMethodNoSuper_nolock(objc_class*, objc_selector*) + 100
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3e0c94 lookUpImpOrForward + 304
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3e0b30 lookUpImpOrNil + 12
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3d73d0 _class_resolveInstanceMethod(objc_class*, objc_selector*, objc_object*) + 128
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3e0cc8 lookUpImpOrForward + 356
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3e0b30 lookUpImpOrNil + 12
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3d75ac class_respondsToSelector_inst + 36
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18f3f27bc -[NSObject respondsToSelector:] + 52
9  UIKit                          0x19680ca60 -[UIGestureRecognizer setDelegate:] + 456
10 CameraUI                       0x1a5ee913c -[CAMViewfinderViewController _createZoomPinchGestureRecognizerIfNecessary]
11 CameraUI                       0x1a5ee8ea0 -[CAMViewfinderViewController _createCommonGestureRecognizersIfNecessary]
12 CameraUI                       0x1a5ee2c6c -[CAMViewfinderViewController viewDidLoad]
13 UIKit                          0x1967e93dc -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1056
14 UIKit                          0x1967e8fa4 -[UIViewController view] + 28
15 CameraUI                       0x1a5fea210 -[CAMCameraViewController loadView]
16 CameraUI                       0x1a5f1905c -[CAMImagePickerCameraViewController loadView]
17 UIKit                          0x1967e9074 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 184
18 UIKit                          0x1968a2fcc -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
19 UIKit                          0x1968a2ea4 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
20 UIKit                          0x1968a21ec -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 140
21 UIKit                          0x1968a1c38 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 856
22 UIKit                          0x196b670a8 -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers_7_0:transition:animated:operation:] + 2956
23 UIKit                          0x196b6614c -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:operation:] + 748
24 UIKit                          0x196b652a8 __54-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]_block_invoke + 1300
25 UIKit                          0x196b51d78 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128
26 UIKit                          0x19691f3d4 -[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:] + 412
27 UIKit                          0x196a44d50 -[UIImagePickerController _setupControllersForCurrentSourceType] + 184
28 UIKit                          0x196a44bf8 -[UIImagePickerController viewWillAppear:] + 84
29 UIKit                          0x196801210 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 624
30 UIKit                          0x196800f88 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
31 UIKit                          0x196b37780 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 1096
32 UIKit                          0x196a7b074 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
33 UIKit                          0x196a6ce28 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 560
34 UIKit                          0x1967dbb80 _afterCACommitHandler + 168
35 CoreFoundation                 0x19094d7dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
36 CoreFoundation                 0x19094b40c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
37 CoreFoundation                 0x19094b89c __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
38 CoreFoundation                 0x19087a048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
39 GraphicsServices               0x1922fd198 GSEventRunModal + 180
40 UIKit                          0x196854628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
41 UIKit                          0x19684f360 UIApplicationMain + 208
42 Haraj                          0x10009b3dc main (main.m:22)
43 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f85c5b8 (Missing)
```

Any help on how to fix crashes like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384804/crash-on-xcode-8-0-gm-iphone-simulator-ios-10. It seems like you are missing some required keys in info.plist. iOS 10 has added restrictions.

Comment: Thanks! NSCameraUsageDescription was missing.

Comment: Wait, @AbdullahUmer do u even use the camera on your app? Because I'm with the same issue but turns out I'm not using the camera anywhere. The only 3rd party lib which even mentions the word camera is DeviceKit and nobody seems to face this issue. Anyways, added the key to my plist file and will pray for the crashes to go away. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I'm using camera in my app.